# Batch - Variable substring in a For loop, with variable range

Tags: batch-file, cmd

For the record, seeing that this type of questions is pretty popular on SO, I read around 30 answers in SO and couldn't find a question and answer that fit perfectly to my needs.

I have the following snippet:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set string=test

for /l %%l in (0,1,1) do (
    set /A remainder=%%l %%2
    if remainder equ 1 (
        set /A curr=%%l+1
        call set res=!string:~-%curr%,1!
        echo !res!
        )
    )
```

When executed this way, I get:
`string:~-curr`

How do I get the line with the variable substring with variable range - `call set res=!string:~-%curr%,1!`, to execute properly? For instance, for the second index (1), I want it to execute as if `set res=!string:~-2,1!` is written there.

How do I solve this?

Comment: `if remainder equ 1` compares the string `remainder` with the string `1` (that would never be true). You need `if !remainder! equ 1`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot use normal (immediate) expansion for the variable `curr` since you write *and* read it in the same block of code. However, since nested delayed expansion (like `!string:~-!curr!,1!`) does not work (because `!string:~-!` and `!,1!` were seen as variables then, and the former was even invalid syntax), you could use an interim `for` loop:

```cmd
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set "string=test"

for /L %%l in (0,1,1) do (
    set /A "remainder=%%l%%2"
    if !remainder! equ 1 (
        set /A "curr=%%l+1"
        for %%k in (!curr!) do (
            set "res=!string:~-%%k,1!"
            echo(!res!
        )
    )
)
endlocal
```

(I prefer this over the approach `call set "res=%%string:~-!curr!,1%%"`, because `call` may introduce trouble with the caret symbol `^` and it is slower.)

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea, what your code is supposed to do, but to clear the error you mention:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set string=test

for /l %%l in (0,1,1) do (
    set /A remainder=%%l %%2
    if !remainder! equ 1 (
        set /A curr=%%l+1
        call set res=%%string:~-!curr!,1%%
        echo !res!
    )
)
```